# Facebook Open Graph Meta Tags in Body

Tags: facebook, wordpress, facebook-opengraph

Can someone help solve this problem with meta tags in body?
I have a wordpress site and I'm using the open graph wordpress plugin to make the facebook image default to the featured image. It is not working properly. When I debug it on the opengraph debugger, I get ...

*

> **Meta Tags In Body**Your page has meta tags in the body instead of the head. This may be because your HTML was malformed and they fell
>   lower in the parse tree. Please fix this in order for the tags to be
>   usable.

*
Can anyone look quickly at the debug link and tell me how to fix it? Here is a sample URL: http://wilmettefeed.com/wh-42/

thanks!

Comment: There're no meta tags in the body of the link you provided. It's either the wrong link or the debugger doesn't work properly.

Answer (score 1):

Your HTML, indeed is malformed. On line one of your document the source shows:

```
<div id="nmlurkoverlay">
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US" xmlns:og="http://ogp.me/ns#">
```

A function somewhere is outputting code before the *wp_header();* function. Could it be your *justified-image-grid* plugin? Or whatever involves outputting **id="nmlurkoverlay"**. Find and fix this, and you will resolve your *Facebook Open Graph* Tags issue.

Comment: You are correct! Thank you so much. That was just a dumb mistake on my part. That immediately fixed the problem. Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0):

The `<div id="nmlurkoverlay">` could come from a function, but could also be hard coded in the header.php file in your active template folder. Check there first.